# ? zmq.libzmq imported from - Building 'dist\main.exe'. error: [WinError 87] the parameter is incorrect. PY2EXE

Tags: python, zeromq, py2exe, pyzmq, mediapipe

I want to convert my python file `main.py` into an executable. I'm using Py2exe to do this.
This is my code.
Setup for the conversion
`    from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

```
 setup(
 options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
 windows = \[{'script': "main.py"}\],
 zipfile = None,
 )\`
```

Main
`import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import pyautogui

def show_webcam():
scale = 10

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh.FaceMesh(refine_landmarks=True)
screen_w, screen_h = pyautogui.size()

while True:
    _, frame = camera.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    height, width, channels = frame.shape
    #cropping
    centerX, centerY = int(height/2), int(width/2)
    radiusX, radiusY = int(scale*height/100), int(scale*width/100)
    minX, maxX = centerX - radiusX, centerX + radiusX
    minY, maxY = centerY-radiusY, centerY+radiusY
    cropped = frame[minX:maxX, minY:maxY]
    resized_cropped = cv2.resize(cropped, (width, height))

    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(resized_cropped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    output = face_mesh.process(rgb_frame)
    landmark_points = output.multi_face_landmarks
    # print(landmark_points)
    frame_h, frame_w, _ = resized_cropped.shape
    if landmark_points:
        landmarks = landmark_points[0].landmark
        for id, landmark in enumerate(landmarks[473:478]):
            x = int(landmark.x * frame_w)
            y = int(landmark.y * frame_h)
            cv2.circle(resized_cropped, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 0))
            if id == 1:
                screen_x = screen_w / frame_w * x
                screen_y = screen_h / frame_h * y
                try:
                    pyautogui.moveTo(screen_x, screen_y) 
                except pyautogui.FailSafeException:
                    print('Running code before exiting.')
                    break
                pyautogui.moveTo(screen_x, screen_y)
        # LEFT CLICK
        left = [landmarks[145], landmarks[159]]
        for landmark in left:
            x = int(landmark.x * frame_w)
            y = int(landmark.y * frame_h)
            cv2.circle(resized_cropped, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 255))
        if (left[0].y - left[1].y) < 0.04:
            # print('click')
            pyautogui.click()
            pyautogui.sleep(1)

    cv2.imshow('Eyes Controlled Mouse', resized_cropped)
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    # if Esc key is press then break out of the loop 
    if key == 27: 
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

def main():
show_webcam()

if **name** == '**main**':
main()`

If I run `python main.py py2exe` I get this error
`? zmq.libzmq imported from - Building 'dist\main.exe'. error: [WinError 87] the parameter is incorrect.`

Could anyone help me?